# PHP Counter for a unique reference from a button

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to use a counter to give me a unique referencing system. I want to click a button which then checks a field/file with the last number in it and then simply adds 1 to it then inserts it into a fields on screen?

not sure the best way of doing this or exactly how to do this as i'm still learning php.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This would be done with Javascript more than PHP. Check out [jQuery's .append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing where you number is stored, is it in the DB or is it in the same scope etc? If it's within the same scope you could do something like: $newnumber = $unique + 1;

Comment: im using MySQL so it would be good to have it in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count() query in sql and just add one.

Here's the [count](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) tutorials.

One there. assign the query into a new variable and increment it:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;");
$q++;
```

Comment: so if I create a new table and a field called "count" within that table, and just used that code it will pull the number from that field and just add one?